# How to remove a folder that starts with “$”?

Tags: shell, quoting, filenames

I created a directory named "$pattern" and now when ever i try to remove it, it says

> pattern: Undefined variable.

I have tried:

```
$ rm -r $pattern
$ rm -rf $pattern
$ rm "$ option[value='2016']"
```

Comment: In what shell, Vipanchi?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`$`, space, `'` and `[` are special characters in most shells. To remove their special meaning, you have to use the quoting mechanisms of the shell.

The [quoting syntax varies very much with the shell](/a/296147).

In all shells that I know, you can use single quotes to quote all characters but single quote, backslash and newline (in Bourne-like shells, it does quote the last two as well, except in backticks for `\` in some).

```
rm -r '$pattern'
```

Should work in most common shells.

```
rm -r \$pattern
```

Would work (except inside backticks for Bourne-like ones) in all shells but those of the `rc` family.

Same for:

```
rm "\$option[value='2016']"
```

In `rc`-like shells, you'd use:

```
rm '$option[value=''2016'']'
```

Answer (score 16):

If directory is empty:

```
rmdir \$pattern
```

Otherwise:

```
rm -r \$pattern
```

(It will delete recursevely any file that the folder contains)

Comment: You can also singlequote to avoid escaping: `rm '$pattern'`

Answer (score 3):

When you need to operate on a file which contains special characters, an option is to use the bash autocomplete feature: start typing your command (in this case `rmdir`) and then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> several times. This will cycle around all the files/directory in the current directory, automatically escaping all special characters.

This also works well if you're operating on very long filenames.

Comment: *"This will cycle around ..."* - not by default; you need to [bind TAB to `menu-complete` instead of `complete`](/q/146690).

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you can delete the file based on the inode number. First list all the files in the current directory with the inode numbers

```
ls-il
```

then using the first number of the printout for your corresponding file name, you can use the following command to delete based on the inode number

```
find . -inum [inode-number] -exec rm -i {} \;
```

Example

```
$ ls -il
total 0
804743 -rw-r--r--  1 staff  0 Nov  2 19:49 test1
804744 -rw-r--r--  1 staff  0 Nov  2 19:49 test2

$ find . -inum 804743 -exec rm -i {} \;
remove ./test1? y

$ ls -il
total 0
804744 -rw-r--r--  1  staff  0 Nov  2 19:49 test2
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply escape the character using a "\", this is also a common practice used in writing SQL queries in web applications to prevent execution of database commands other than the ones intended.